# How to choose MTB bike tyre: hookless, tubular or clincher?

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, rims

I don't know the difference between hookless tire, tubular tire and clincher tire. When I choose the tire type how to make a professional choice? I want to know which tire type is best for me.

Comment: You don't really have a choice -- your rim determines what kind of tires you use.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Helen. What do you mean by *professional choice*?

Comment: Could you tell us which use you are going to make of this tyres : XC, enduro, downhill?

Comment: Yes I want to choose a kind of rim and tire. I don't know which is better for training and race

Comment: Is there a difference between XC, ENDURO and DH?

Comment: Based on that last comment, you want a clincher tyre.   Now you get to choose tread pattern, tubed or tubeless, and tyre cross sectional area(height).  Most likely your wheel size is fixed by the frame you have.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the tyres that fit the rims on your bike. If you were a professional you'd use whatever your sponsor told you to, so that's a bit of a side issue.

Tubulars are back in the MTB world, but they're still rare and it's unlikely your bike has them. I suggest not buying a tubular wheelset, let your sponsors do that when they decide it's a good idea.

[Hookless rims](http://www.bikeradar.com/au/mtb/gear/article/trail-tech-off-the-hook-40749/) have [some advantages](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/24614/hookless-rim-benefits) but not to the point where I would throw away hooked rims to buy them. That assumes you're running tubeless, the advantages of a hookless composite rim with tubed tyres are pretty imaginary.